# Size of Dlls built using VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I had a project in VS2013. I used VS2015 to build the same project. I observe that the size of dlls built differs by more than double. Dlls built using VS2015 are around 40kb while the ones built using vs2013 are 80kb.
Is it expected or am I missing something?

Comment: Language? Debug/Release?

Comment: C# for both Debug and Release I see this change.

Comment: VS2015 uses a completely new compiler so differences are not unexpected. You could use Ildasm.exe to see if there are big differences in the IL code.